# generate file with correct output python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python code which I am using to generate the batch file and the input is coming from txt file

```
def create_bat_file(lp=None):
  with open(r"test.txt", "r+") as file:
    currentDir = os.path.abspath(".")
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
      a = line.split('=')
      b = a[0]
      f = a[1]
      bk = a[2]
      reldat = a[3]
      f= open("{}.bat".format(f),"w+")
      f.write("@ECHO OFF\n")
      f.write("SET lp="'"{}"'"\n".format(lp))
      if b == "RB":
          f.write("SET reldat="'"{}"'"".format(reldat))
      if b == "RB":
        f.write("{}\\a.exe POST -d "'"best.variable.lp=lp"'"" " " "{}".format(currentDir,bk))
      else:
        f.write("{}\\a.exe POST -d "'"best.variable.cp=cp"'"" " " "{}".format(currentDir,bk))
      f.close()
```

test.txt file is having below input

```
CL=TEST14=https://test.com.org/latst/queue/TEST-R=2020-12-22
```

Below is the output

```
@ECHO OFF
SET lp="test"
SET reldate="2020-12-22
"C:\a.exe POST -d "best.variable.cp"=cp https://test.com.org/rest/api/latest/queue/TEST-RR
```

Issue is when it creates the batch file (TEST14.bat)

```
Wrong:

SET reldate="2020-12-22
    "C:\a.exe POST -d "best.variable.cp"=cp https://test.com.org/rest/api/latest/queue/TEST-RR
```

in output the end double quote comes to the next line
it should be always like

```
Correct:

SET reldate="2020-12-22"
C:\a.exe POST -d "best.variable.cp"=cp https://test.com.org/rest/api/latest/queue/TEST-RR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last character of `line` is the newline character `\n`. The last character of `reldat` is also the newline character. Therefore, on the line:

```
f.write("SET reldat="'"{}"'"".format(reldat))
```

You end up adding a `\n` before the last `"`.

To fix, you can strip the `\n` from `line` and add the missing one where it is needed:

```
def create_bat_file(lp=None):
  with open(r"test.txt", "r+") as file:
    currentDir = os.path.abspath(".")
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
      line = line[:-1]  #### STRIP NEWLINE CHARACTER ####
      a = line.split('=')
      b = a[0]
      f = a[1]
      bk = a[2]
      reldat = a[3]
      f= open("{}.bat".format(f),"w+")
      f.write("@ECHO OFF\n")
      f.write("SET lp="'"{}"'"\n".format(lp))
      if b == "RB":
          f.write('SET reldat="{}"\n'.format(reldat))  #### ADD MISSING NEWLINE ####
      if b == "RB":
        f.write("{}\\a.exe POST -d "'"best.variable.lp=lp"'"" " " "{}".format(currentDir,bk))
      else:
        f.write("{}\\a.exe POST -d "'"best.variable.cp=cp"'"" " " "{}".format(currentDir,bk))
      f.close()
```

I also took the freedom to use single quotes around the string, it looks much better!